# Remove double space in a string

Tags: objective-c, string

I'm having a few strings, all of them having excess white spaces in the end. Having just 1 space there is not a problem, but outputting these strings in their current state into a (editable) textfield, places the cursor ~10 white spaces too far.

How can I remove double spaces in a string using Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions. If you're talking about trimming whitespaces from the end of a string, you could use the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` method as follows:

```
NSString *dirtyString = @"String with whitespaces at the end           ";
NSString *cleanString = [dirtyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Incidentally, I've choosen to use the `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` [NSCharacterSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCharacterSet) - the *pure* answer to your question would be to instead use the `whitespaceCharacterSet`, but I suspect that you probably also want to remove any trailing linebreaks, etc.

However, if there are double spaces *within* the string which you want to remove then, the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString * trimmedString = [@"string with spaces at the end    " stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 1):

can your try

```
NSString *trimmedString = [dirtyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

good luck